# browser not reflecting updated url after window.history.replaceState

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the url of the page using replaceState. From my application I fire `history.replaceState({}, "", "asdasd");`
The url in the browser does not update after this.

When I log `window.location.href` is gives me the updated url but the url in the browser still stays as is.

If I fire the same line of code from the console it works correctly and the url is also changed instantly. I am testing my application using localhost. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is working with asp.net, IE and Chrome. It is updating the browser url. Can you add more details and code how you are executing it from your application?

Comment: Am using javascript, I have a function that only calls replaceState: `function() {window.history.replaceState({}, "", "asdasd");}`

Comment: It works for me from the console, however, not from the application

Comment: Try wrapping your code with window.setTimeout and check if it works correctly: `window.setTimeout(() => {history.replaceState({}, "", "asdasd");}, 0);`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be due to the timing of the `history.replaceState()` call in your application code. While the URL might be updated, the browser's address bar might not reflect the change immediately.

To ensure the URL update is promptly reflected in the address bar, you can try wrapping your `history.replaceState()` call in a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 0 milliseconds. This action defers the execution of `history.replaceState()` until the next event loop iteration, allowing the browser to update the URL:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    history.replaceState({}, "", "asdasd");
}, 0);
```